# Admin Dashboard not working after adding Sirena theme (from envato marketplace)

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, exception, dashboard

I purchased Magento Theme from Envato Marketplace & added to my store as per there guidelines. Tried many different times and on different servers & at last when logging into the admin panel, I'm getting error `Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Meigee_Core::themes)`

**Full Error**

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Meigee_Core::themes)

Exception #0 (OutOfRangeException): Specified invalid parent id (Meigee_Core::themes)
<pre>#1 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003d662cea0000000050a71442#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003d662cea0000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003d662cea0000000050a71442#), array(array('SetupMenuBuilder'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:39]
#4 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->getResult(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000003d662cea0000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:148]
#5 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->_initMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Menu/Config.php:111]
#6 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config->getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:364]
#7 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->_getMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php:324]
#8 Magento\Backend\Model\Url->getStartupPageUrl() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:281]
#9 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->_processUrlKeys() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:50]
#10 Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->_processUrlKeys() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:175]
#11 Magento\Backend\App\Request\BackendValidator->validate(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#, &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003d662cf20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/CompositeValidator.php:40]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\Request\CompositeValidator->validate(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#, &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003d662cf20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:138]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#, &Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor#000000003d662cf20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000003d662fc20000000050a71442#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000003d662fb00000000050a71442#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

I'm using Magento 2.3.2 on AWS Lightsail.

I have wasted 2 days on Google to avoid this issue but no success.

I might be missing some basic stuff, I don't know, but any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check your app/code/Meigee directory. Inside that directory is there any Core module available or not ?

Comment: Hi @KishanSavaliya,

I might sound silly, but inside app/code/Meigee - there are only 5 folders none of them is Core.

Comment: Yes, Core directory is missing there so you're getting this error.

Comment: So by adding a folder named "Core" it will be resolved?

Comment: No, If you purchased that theme then inside that theme may be core directory available.

Comment: I checked - but there is no such directory in the purchased theme.

Could you help me by explaining how do you know that Core dir might be missing?

Comment: Please look at your error that contains this **"Meigee_Core::themes"**

Comment: Okay, so is there any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, Please find this in your menu.xml file in app/code/Meigee/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml file

Comment: Such directory path after "app/code/Meigee/" does not exist @KishanSavaliya

Comment: Module means any one of five inside app/code/Megiee

Comment: okay, there are 5 modules so do I have to search all menu.xml files for "Meigee_Core::themes"

And what if I find 1?

Comment: Then please rename that menu.xml file for some time from menu to menu1 and then clear Magento cache using command. and then refresh the page

Comment: okay, let me try it first.

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, I tried what you suggested - now the error has changed and saying Specified invalid parent id (Meigee_Core::extensions)?

Comment: Now find this extensions and remove it

Comment: What is our aim here by renaming/removing these files? Don't we need them?

Comment: You can see menu in left sidebar in admin panel. If you have core module available then you can add that module otherwise please try to replace Megiee_Core with your current module name.

Answer (score 0):

You do not added Megiee Core module there. So you're getting this issue.

Please try to install Core module in your theme, otherwise please check your `menu.xml` file and replace this `Megiee_Core` Some other module which is available.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if you need help here then.

Comment: Technically Megiee_Core module should already be there in the purchase. It's very irritating why it's not there. I have thoroughly checked the directory. I don't know how to fix it. If removing a few lines from code It's just getting worse with new errors.

Comment: Yes, Because in Megiee theme they used Core module's Block, helpers and other files in other module as well so you need to find app/code/Megiee/Core directory in your paid theme. Otherwise you will get new errors when you fix one you get another one.

Comment: I checked it again - but no Core OR Megiee_Core directory included in the theme.

Comment: You can contact Support team of Megiee, they will definitely helps you to configure theme.

Comment: Yes, have raised the ticket, it's been 4 days now - got no response from them - that's why I posted this here :(